# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election, announcement

[The 2020 Community Moderator Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. **Nomination** phase
2. **Primary** phase
3. **Election** phase

The nomination phase began on July 6, 2020. The election will end on July 21, 2020 at 20:00.

Please visit the official election page at **https://stackoverflow.com/election/12** for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on Meta—just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).