# Why was the latest election mistakenly started three times?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, moderator-election, community-bulletin

It looks like the latest (2020) moderator election was mistakenly started three times, resulting in some weirdness.

The election shows/showed up three times in the meta sidebar, once with a different end date:

> [image: 3x election]

The automatic Community user meta announcement was also posted three times: [once](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399104/2020-community-moderator-election), [twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399108/2020-community-moderator-election), and [thrice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399110/2020-community-moderator-election).

Finally, this resulted in some issues with notifications as well: over on the global meta, someone posted a [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350474/received-inbox-message-about-election-that-is-underway-but-there-is-no-active-e) about being notified of an election but seeing no election when they followed it. (It seems like they followed it during the time between one of the elections.)

What happened here?

Comment: It was started three times to test who would post on Meta about it. You won.

Comment: @rene I object. I [won](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350474/received-inbox-message-about-election-that-is-underway-but-there-is-no-active-e)! :D

Comment: The first try at the election ended prematurely after 10 minutes with no victor. Looks like attempts to restart it have resulted in duplicate, spurious announcement posts (but I'm still waiting for my duplicate, spurious *Caucus* badges).

Comment: we need more moderators, so instead of increasing the number, they are running 3 elections at the same time

Comment: Well, a [Cat](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4548692/catija) walked across the keyboard. We keep trying to tell her that's a terrible way to type...

Comment: @Machavity My cats are excellently trained. They write great prose but need a bit of practice on poetry.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One of the developers mistakenly ended the SO election early instead of the [Russian Language Election](https://rus.stackexchange.com/election/2) that needed to be ended early.

When setting things up again the date for the election to begin was mistakenly set as Tuesday (when it should end) so the dates got changed again to fix that.

The first start, the second start with the wrong date and the third correct start account for the three announcements/shenanigans that happened.

We'll investigate what's weird with the bulletin and fix it.

Update: Bulletin is now fixed.

Comment: Dang Russians interfering with elections again...

Comment: This has now been resolved. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Bulletin needs a hard cache reset as far as I can tell. Is that really what "fixed" it? (Useful for future issues)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou yes, and a firm *bang* on top of the server to have it behave again ....

Comment: @rene what if the server is virtual? Or hosted 1000 miles away? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou they run on bare metal. And at least one SRE lives near New Jersey so at most that is a 30 minute metro ride ...

Comment: They clearly need a robot arm to bang on the top of the server...

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou No, it wasn't just cache, there were actually three items in the bulletin, so two needed to be deleted.